# Laravel Process() with FFMPEG times out for any video that is even kind of large

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, ffmpeg

I am creating an application that lets users upload video files, and once they do it will convert them all to .mp4's (it does some other things, but since this first part of the code is breaking before it gets a chance to reach the other stuff, and the process for each is pretty similar, lets just discuss this issue).

Once a user submits, it gets sent to GameController@store. Below is a code sample (the one that keeps getting sent back to me as problematic) from the controller:

```
$process = new Process(env('APP_FFMPEG', 'ffmpeg') . ' -i ' . $fileURL . ' -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -profile:v main -c:a aac -movflags +faststart ' . $newFileName . ' -hide_banner');
              $process->setTimeout(360);
              $process->setIdleTimeout(60);
              $process->run();
              if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
              }
```

I am using the Symfony Process() class to run the FFMpeg conversion. The weird thing is, when I run this with a 1 or 2 second video, it goes without a hitch. This, to me, rules out issues like path problems, permission problems, etc. Multiple file types work with this, as long as they are very short. As soon as I put in a video that is even around 1min, it returns with this:

```
The process "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_26/team_1_game_26_vid_1.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -profile:v main -c:a aac -movflags +faststart storage/team_1_folder/game_26/convertedVideo_1.mp4 -hide_banner" exceeded the timeout of 360 seconds.
```

Now, notice that it says 'timeout of 360 seconds'. That is because I have also edited ALL of the possible timeout constraints, as well as the file size constraints that I can think of. Here is what I have done:

-Changed php.ini (in my MAMP installation) values:
--max_execution_time = 300 (default was 30)
--memory_limit = 1280M (default was 128)
--post_max_size = 800M
--upload_max_filesize = 3200M
-max_input_time=300

-In the GameController (code above)
--$process->setTimeout(360);
--$process->setTimeout(360);

After all that, with a big file, the thing will just stall for the 6 minutes that I have set on the timeout thing, and then send an error. Is FFmpeg just stalling, or is this a process issue? Who knows. Errors surrounding these things are just beautifully vague.

I have tagged Laravel, PHP, and FFmpeg in hopes that someone will recognize this issue. I know that Process() is sending me the error, but since it is sending me a timeout, I don't know what is at fault.

**I'm not ruling anything out, so hit me with ideas, even crazy ones!**

**Edit**
Here is the output of the -report. I cut some of it off because the end part gets repetitive and goes for literally 1000 lines:

```
ffmpeg started on 2019-06-24 at 18:50:23
Report written to "ffmpeg-20190624-185023.log"
Command line:
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -profile:v main -c:a aac -movflags +faststart storage/team_1_folder/game_31/convertedVideo_1.mp4 -report
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp4'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'medium'.
Reading option '-profile:v' ... matched as option 'profile' (set profile) with argument 'main'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-movflags' ... matched as AVOption 'movflags' with argument '+faststart'.
Reading option 'storage/team_1_folder/game_31/convertedVideo_1.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4.
[NULL @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Opening 'http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4' for reading
[http @ 0x7f9ad3c6b540] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Starting connection attempt to ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3e00400] Successfully connected to ::1 port 80
[http @ 0x7f9ad3c6b540] request: GET /storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.20.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: localhost
Icy-MetaData: 1


[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Starting connection attempt to ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c6b840] Successfully connected to ::1 port 80
[http @ 0x7f9ad3c6b540] request: GET /storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.20.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=170169585-
Connection: close
Host: localhost
Icy-MetaData: 1


[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 10584600
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 0 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 0, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 1 ctts: 4002, ctts_index: 1, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 1000 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 2, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 2001 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 3, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 3002 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 4, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 4003 ctts: 4004, ctts_index: 5, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 5004 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 6, ctts_count: 10575
```

**Edit 2**
I also found this towards the bottom:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 10582571 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 10573, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] stts: 10583572 ctts: 1001, ctts_index: 10574, ctts_count: 10575
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Setting codecpar->delay to 1 for stream st: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 15563816
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 170509020 bytes read:372203 seeks:1 nb_streams:2
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Address ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Address 127.0.0.1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Starting connection attempt to ::1 port 80
[tcp @ 0x7f9ad3c72d40] Successfully connected to ::1 port 80
[http @ 0x7f9ad3c6b540] request: GET /storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.20.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=48-
Connection: close
Host: localhost
Icy-MetaData: 1


[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad4811200] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9ad480ae00] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 308454 bytes read:680609 seeks:2 frames:2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://localhost/storage/team_1_folder/game_31/team_1_game_31_vid_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:05:52.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3865 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und), 1, 1/30000: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3730 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url storage/team_1_folder/game_31/convertedVideo_1.mp4.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mp4.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument libx264.
Applying option profile:v (set profile) with argument main.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument aac.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: storage/team_1_folder/game_31/convertedVideo_1.mp4.
[file @ 0x7f9ad3f02740] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3dbcc00] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3dbcc00] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3dbcc00] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3dbcc00] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3dbcc00] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3c71040] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x7f9ad3c71040] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9ad3e00440] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] no picture 
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805800] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/30000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f9ad3dbfb80] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/30000 fr:30000/1001 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0x7f9ad3dc0100] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9ad3c6e880] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[libx264 @ 0x7f9ad5811200] using mv_range_thread = 88
[libx264 @ 0x7f9ad5811200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f9ad5811200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f9ad5811200] profile Main, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f9ad5811200] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'storage/team_1_folder/game_31/convertedVideo_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/30000: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und), 0, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805800] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805800] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805800] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5813a00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5804c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
[h264 @ 0x7f9ad5805200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000999
```

Comment: Show the log (without `-hide_banner`) from an instance of an ffmpeg command that causes the timeout message.

Comment: Ok one second, let me run it again and grab it for you

Comment: Hmm, so when I run this all I get is the error from Symfony. How should I go about getting the ffmpeg error?

Comment: One method is to add the `-report` option which will generate an excessively verbose log file in the current directory.

Comment: I just edited to include the output

Comment: Added a bit more non-repetitive output I found towards the bottom

Comment: What about 'max_input_time=60' in php.ini

Comment: Imran it is set at 60. I'll try increasing that. However, my concern is also that this process (even for a long-ish video) shouldn't take longer than 60 seconds. Still, let me try it.

Comment: Same problem as before, I couldn't get it to go through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a day of beating my head against the wall, I woke up this morning and figured out my problem.

My mistake was simply in that I did not understand the limitations of FFMPEG well enough. Doing the conversion that I have ordered above takes a LONG time. I am running this exact thing in my own terminal now, and boy, it sure does take a while. For a 5 minute video it is at minute 13 and counting.

If anyone else stumbles across this, just really make sure that you understand the program you are running in the Process() command and think if what you are asking it to do is reasonable.